# The integrals $\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{ e^{-i z u}}{z \pm i c }dz $

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform, contour-integration, complex-integration

I would like to evaluate the two integrals
$$I_\pm(u) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{ e^{-i z u}}{z \pm i c }dz  $$
where $c$ is a positive real constant. I expect these each to be a real exponential times some Heaviside function, but I'm having trouble showing this. Can anyone offer guidance? I figure this is trivial for someone with more contour integration experience.

So far, concentrating on the integral $I_-(u)$, I attempted to use the semicircle contour depicted below:

[image]

Evaluating the residue at $z=ic$, this provides

$$I_-(u)  = i e^{uc} - \lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^\pi d\theta \frac{iRe^{i\theta} \exp(-i R e^{i\theta} u )}{Re^{i\theta} - ic}$$

I suppose this limit depends on the sign of $u$ and therefore introduces a heaviside function? Shooting in the dark here...

Comment: this comment is just to note that the integral just exists as a principal value, as $\int_{-\infty }^0 \frac{e^{-ixu}}{x\pm ic}dx$ and $\int_{0}^\infty \frac{e^{-ixu}}{x\pm ic}$ can't converge both for any chosen $c,u\in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why people don't realize rectangular contours are more natural than semicircles.. It is mostly obvious that for $u <0$, $\lim_{R\to \infty} \int_{\partial [-R,R] + i[0,R]} \frac{e^{-izu}}{z-ic}dz = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-izu}}{z-ic}dz$. Apply the residue theorem to the LHS. For $u>0$ the integrand in the LHS has exponential growth so we look instead at $\lim_{R\to \infty} \int_{\partial [-R,R] - i[0,R]} \frac{e^{-izu}}{z-ic}dz = -\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-izu}}{z-ic}dz$.  The LHS is $0$ by Cauchy's integral theorem.

Comment: Thanks @reuns. This helps. The choice of contour depending on the sign of $u$ is the element I was missing. I'm curious about your statement on rectangular contours. In what sense mathematically are they typically more natural?